# didSelectRowAtIndexPath for calling new Thread

Tags: xcode, multithreading, selector, didselectrowatindexpath

I've this code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but I want to optimize code for make a new thread that push a view controller whit my data from a JSON parser.

```
    #pragma mark - DidselectRow

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //SPINNER
    [spinner startAnimating];


    //[self performSelector:@selector(pushDetailView:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0.1];

    /*
    int *riga = indexPath.row;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(pushDetailView) toTarget:self withObject:riga];
    */

    NSLog(@"Seleziono l'immagine: %@", [photoTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    //creo un'istanza di DettaglioView
    DettaglioView *dettaglioImmagine = [[DettaglioView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DettaglioView" bundle:nil];



    //Inseirsco il titolo nella Navigation BAR della vista
    dettaglioImmagine.titoloSource = [photoTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    dettaglioImmagine.imageCoverSource = [photoURLsLargeImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"imageCoverSource: %@",  dettaglioImmagine.imageCoverSource);


    //passo alla vista del DettaglioView con l'animazione usando il pushViewController
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dettaglioImmagine animated:YES];


    //pulisco lo style della cella selezionata togliendo il fondino blu
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //Attivo la vibrazione
    [self buzz];
}
```

Now I wish make an external method from didSelectRowAtIndexPath for push the detail view like this:

```
- (void)pushDetailView:(NSInteger *)idRow {

    // Push the detail view here
}
```

Now my problem is, How Can I pass the indexPath. row method to pushDetailView?

***I've try this but It doesn't work***

```
int *riga = indexPath.row;
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(pushDetailView) toTarget:self withObject:riga];
```

Answer (score 0):

Any user interface tasks **ABSOLUTELY MUST** run on main thread. This is not an option, background UI manipulation can and will raise exception. You have to load your data in background before you push new viewController on main thread.

Comment: Well But I've a problem with my "Spinne" that is a UIActivityIndicator.

Comment: Well I've a problem to resolve for my spinner that is a UIActivityIndicator that not start when the user click on the cell in my UITableview.

I've define in my init this activityIndicator

spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
UIBarButtonItem * barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:spinner];
[self navigationItem].rightBarButtonItem = barButton;

Answer (score 0):

You cant pass int. instead int -> nsnumber or nsstring that can be retained